# Number of Successive Cells of a Same Value in Spotfire

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I am wondering if it is possible to created a calculated column that will count how many cells of the same value are successive (i.e., next to each other) so that I can divide it by the total number of cells in that column. (I'm only looking at 1's and 0's in the column. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated as I've been scratching my head over this for a while,

[image]

The percentages at the bottom of the columns is simply = (the number of 1's touching another 1) / (total # of rows) --> my end goal

Comment: Good morning, can you provide a sample dataset and expected output? This is important since you want to count successive values, the ordering matters.

Comment: Just added, thanks for the suggested edit - I forgot my table would be changed with a simple copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this has to be done in a few steps.

- Insert a calculated column `RowId()` and name it `rid`
- Insert a calculated column with this expression, and name it [TouchingA]:

`If(([Location A]=1) and (([Location A]=First([Location A]) over
 (Next([rid]))) or ([Location A]=First([Location A]) over
 (Previous([rid])))),1,0)`

- Insert a calculated column with this expression, and name it [TouchingB]:

`If(([Site B]=1) and (([Site B]=First([Site B]) over (Next([rid]))) or
([Site B]=First([Site B]) over (Previous([rid])))),1,0)`

At this point, your data will look like this:

[image: SpotfireTouching]

Next, insert a `CROSS TABLE` and set the Horizontal Axis = `(Column Names)`, the Vertical Axis = `(None)`, and the Cell Values = `Sum([TouchingA]) / Max([rid]) as [A Percent], 
Sum([TouchingB]) / Max([rid]) as [B Percent]`

This will show you the values you want, like below. Of course you can sett his in a calculated value in a text area or anywhere else you want with the proper IF or CASE statement. Lastly, you can change the formatting to make the value a % versus decimal.

[image]

Comment: @FLgeo, i'm also a fan of whiskey, let us know if you run into any other issues!

Comment: I have another question (a twist on this questions) - should I post here or as a completely new question?

Comment: @FLgeo i'd open a new questions so more people will see it. However, you can always link this question to it (just paste the URL in your question) so people will have a reference point.

Comment: Great, will do! Thanks!

Comment: I added the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836127/calcuated-column-for-adjacent-cells-of-a-specific-value-in-spotfire