# Calculated Column for Adjacent Cells of a Specific Value in Spotfire

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I am wondering if it is possible to create a calculated column that will count how many cells of the same value (and only this value) are successive (i.e., next to each other) so that I can divide it by the total number of cells in that column. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated as I've been scratching my head over this for a while. This is an update to a previous question I posted (link below)

**This new question has the key differences below:
(1) I only want to count the number of "Blue" cells that are adjacent to other "Blue" cells
(2) I would like to do this for (over) each Site**

[image]

Previous question is here: [Number of Successive Cells of a Same Value in Spotfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569102/number-of-successive-cells-of-a-same-value-in-spotfire)

Comment: Hey FLgeo can you elaborate on next to each other and adjacent? In SITE A it looks like you only want the Adjacent = 1 if they are touching, but SITE A value 7 has a 1 but isn't  touching any other blues. Is this just a typo?

Comment: @scsimon Yes it is, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to insert your RowID column again, but after that this formula will work for you. You can test by making SiteB, Depth 1 = Blue so that you have two "Blues" touching that are in different sites.

```
If(([Color]="Blue") and 
(([Color]=First([Color]) over (Intersect([Site],Next([rid]))))
or
([Color]=First([Color]) over (Intersect([Site],Previous([rid]))))),1,0)
```

Comment: No worries @FLgeo. Roll Tide.